# File not showing ._COPYING_ in HDFS

Tags: python, hadoop, hdfs, cloudera, bigdata

I am trying to parse one file using python and trying to store it in HDFS. The code was working fine couple of days ago but from today morning i am not getting any error while executing the code but in HDFS directory i am getting **DATA.*COPYING***. It is not at all moving from copying. WHat am i doing wrong.

**Code:**

```
import subprocess
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

cat = subprocess.Popen(["hadoop", "fs", "-cat", "/user/cloudera/pin/*"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
dumpoff = Popen(["hadoop", "fs", "-put", "-", "/user/cloudera/DATA"],stdin=PIPE)
obrInd = "0"
line1 = ""
for line in cat.stdout:
    code = line.split('|')[1]
    idval = line.split('|')[2]
    if (code == "OB"):
        obrInd = runnno
    line1 =line.strip() + "|"+"OB_"+obrInd  
    dumpoff.stdin.write(line1)
    print(line1)
```

**Update:**

```
Configured Capacity: 424169496576 (395.04 GB)
Present Capacity: 348671389696 (324.73 GB)
DFS Remaining: 153408200704 (142.87 GB)
DFS Used: 195263188992 (181.85 GB)
DFS Used%: 56.00%
Under replicated blocks: 0
Blocks with corrupt replicas: 0
Missing blocks: 0
Missing blocks (with replication factor 1): 0

-------------------------------------------------
report: Access denied for user cloudera. Superuser privilege is required
```

Comment: Are your datanodes running?

Comment: how can i check that ? right now all my services are showing good health. Btw i am using Cloudera quick start.

Comment: Check for space issues too. This code works fine on my cluster.

Comment: Thanks @franklinsijo for checking the code. Can you tell me is there any way i can remove unnecessary stuffs from my cloudera.

Comment: Can you update the post with the output of `hdfs dfsadmin -report`. What do you mean by unnecessary stuffs?

Comment: @franklinsijo please check i have updated my question.

Comment: @franklinsijo unnecessary stuffs means logs that get generated after every map reduce.

Comment: I assume the setup has only one datanode. The report shows sufficient space too. Did you try any more attempts?

Comment: @franklinsijo i tried this code 6 time's but it is not working. I am not getting any error as well.

Comment: @franklinsijo i am also getting `failed to move chat popup`.